# ERROR: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to work on this but can't fix it. Can anyone help thanks!

I keep getting the error below when I try to run it. I am using mySQL database.

I get the line 31 highlighted.

[image]

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyApiDBContext _context;

        public CustomerController(MyApiDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Customer
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomers()
        {
            if (_context.Customers == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Customer/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Customers == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return customer;
        }
```

Comment: Have you got nullable reference types turned on?

Comment: Some string is unexpectedly null in the database. It's hard for us to say which one.

Comment: One of the properties of your `Customer` is `string` but the database allows nulls, so try changing it to `string?`. However, without seeing your database structure or your class, we cannot be more specific.

Comment: Use DBNull.Value

Comment: @jdweng Sigh, how do you think OP can do that in the code shown here?

Comment: Thank you, I found the issue. I had set the middle name as not null. I just fixed it by doing "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POCO class Customer, you should have a property of type string. This exception has been raised because the value of that property in DB is null and it can not be cast into string. You may fix it by changing the type of the property to **Nullable< string>** or **string?** .